# Angular 15 :: Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator.(-992007)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular 15 for my application. But getting **Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator.(-992007)** for all the class components

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Angular version : 15.1.13

Node: 18.14.2

Package Manager: npm 9.5.0

Typescript: 4.9.4

Comment: For what do you call `super()`? This class isn't extending any other class.

Comment: No this class isn't extending any other class as of now

Comment: updated code looks fine and versions listed are compatible. Suggest restarting your environment

Comment: @AndrewAllen, I did restarting the environment but still the issue exists